# Check whether the searching attribute exists in a XML file using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have come across couple of similar answers for my question in this form, but could not solve my exact problem. Therefore I am posting this here:

I have an xml file as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <document>
        <user>
            <user_id>0121</user_id>
            <name>Tim</name>
            <file>0121.file</file>
        </user>

        <user>
            <user_id>0178</user_id>
            <name>Henry</name>
            <file>0178.file</file>
        </user>

        <user>
            <user_id>0786</user_id>
            <name>Martin</name>
            <file>0786.file</file>
        </user>

        <user>
            <user_id>1239</user_id>
            <name>Jan</name>
            <file>1239.file</file>
        </user>
    </document>
```

I ask the user to input his user_id and post this user_id and perform a check on the entire xml file to check whether the entered user_id exists in the xml file or not. If exists then I go further if not echo a error message. 
Can anybody pull me out of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT answer**
Forget my previous answer :P

```
$user_id = '1239';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$found = false;
foreach($xml->user AS $user) {
    if ($user->user_id == $user_id) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) echo 'error';
```

Comment: but it think isset() is used to find whether the variable is set or not. But I want to search the whole XML file to find out whether the specified attribute exists or not. I think this is not going to help. Still if you say this helps then I really want to know how?

Answer (score 0):

You could use DOMDocument with DOMXpath query, an example :-

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load(...);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = '//user/user_id[.="0121"]';
$entries = $xpath->query($query);
if ( $entries->length )
{
  // found
}
```